# How to write a generic Database util class in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I want to write a DB util class in groovy which takes some mandatory and optional db params and gives back result as a list of maps.

Groovy class

```
class DBUtil {

    private final String ORACLE="oracle"
    private final String DB2="db2"
    private final String SYBASE="sybase"
    private final String SQLSERVER="sqlserver"
    private final String MSSQLSERVER="mssqlserver"

    private final String ORACLE_DRIVER="jdbc:agra:oracle"
    private final String DB2_DRIVER="jdbc:agra:db2"
    private final String SQLSERVER_DRIVER="jdbc:agra:sqlserver"
    private final String SYBASE_DRIVER="jdbc:agra:sybase"

    private final String ORACLE_DRIVER_CLASS="com.agra.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver"
    private final String DB2_DRIVER_CLASS="com.agra.jdbc.db2.DB2Driver"
    private final String SQLSERVER_DRIVER_CLASS="com.agra.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"
    private final String SYBASE_DRIVER_CLASS="com.agra.jdbc.sybase.SybaseDriver"

    private HashMap<String,String> dbparams
    private HashMap<String,String> sqlStatements

    private String url
    private String username
    private String password
    private String driver
    private String driverClass  

    public void setDbParams(HashMap<String,String> dbparams) {
        this.dbparams=dbparams  
    }

    DBUtil(dbparams, sqlStatements) {
        this.dbparams=dbparams
        this.sqlStatements=sqlStatements
    }

    private void validateDBParams() {
        if (dbparams != null) {
            try {
                if (dbparams?.containsKey("driver")) {
                    driver=dbparams?.get("driver")
                    driverClass=dbparams?.get("driverClass")
                }
                username=dbparams?.get("username")
                password=dbparams?.get("password")
                switch(dbparams?.get("dbtype")) {
                    case ORACLE:
                        if (!dbparams?.containsKey("driver")) {
                            driver=ORACLE_DRIVER
                            driverClass=ORACLE_DRIVER_CLASS
                        }
                        break
                    case DB2:
                        if (!dbparams?.containsKey("driver")) {
                            driver=DB2_DRIVER
                            driverClass=DB2_DRIVER_CLASS
                        }
                        break
                    case SYBASE:
                        if (!dbparams?.containsKey("driver")) {
                            driver=SYBASE_DRIVER
                            driverClass=SYBASE_DRIVER_CLASS
                        }
                        break
                    case SQLSERVER:
                    case MSSQLSERVER:
                        if (!dbparams?.containsKey("driver")) {
                            driver=SQLSERVER_DRIVER
                            driverClass=SQLSERVER_DRIVER_CLASS
                        }
                        break
                }
                url=driver+"://"+dbparams?.get("connectstring")
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Map> execute() {
        List<Map> resultSet;
        def sql
        try {
            if (dbparams != null && sqlStatements != null) {
                validateDBParams()
                //println "$url, $username, $password, $driverClass"
                sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driverClass)
                sqlStatements.each {key, value->
                    List<Map> sqlResult = new ArrayList<Map>()
                    sql.eachRow(value) { row->
                        println row
                    }
                    //resultSet.add(sqlResult)
                    //println sqlResult                             
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException se) {
            println "Exception encountered in DBUtil execute() $se"
        }
        return resultSet
    }

    static main(args) {

        HashMap<String,String> dbparams = ["dbtype":"oracle", "username":"johnkc", "password":"johnc", "connectstring":"apple:1521;SID=ORCL;",
                                            "driver":"jdbc:agra:oracle","driverClass":"com.agra.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver"]
        HashMap<String,String> sqlStatements = ["sql1":"select name, value from v\$parameter",
                    "sql2":"select POO_NAME, POO_VALUE from PO_OPTION"]
        DBUtil db = new DBUtil(dbparams, sqlStatements)
        db.execute()
    }

}
```

After execution it gives me below result (Keys can be more than 2)

```
[NAME:lock_name_space, VALUE:[null]]
[NAME:processes, VALUE:1000]
[NAME:sessions, VALUE:1105]
[POO_NAME:username, POO_VALUE:com.agra.jdbc.base.BaseClob@256ef705]
[POO_NAME:jdbcurl, POO_VALUE:com.agra.jdbc.base.BaseClob@181b7c76]
[POO_NAME:dbType, POO_VALUE:com.agra.jdbc.base.BaseClob@34883357]
[POO_NAME:ConnectionString, POO_VALUE:com.agra.jdbc.base.BaseClob@59e2afb2]
```

How can I place above output in below format (list of maps)?

```
[   "sql1": [ {row1}, {row2}... ],
    "sql2": [ {row1}, {row2}... ],
    ...
]
```

Where row1... = {column1:value1, column2:value2, column3:value3...}

**Update**

Below snippet inside `sqlStatements.each` gives me column names for each

```
def tableColumns=[:]
                sql.rows(value, {meta ->
                    def columns=[]
                    int colCount=meta.columnCount
                    (1..colCount).each{
                        columns.add(meta.getColumnName(it))
                    }
                    tableColumns.put(key, columns)
                })
```

**Update with my solution**

```
public List<Map> execute() {
        List<Map<String,Object>> resultSet=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>()      
        def sql
        try {
            if (dbparams != null && sqlStatements != null) {
                boolean validParams=validateDBParams()
                if (validParams) {
                    sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driverClass)
                    sqlStatements.each {key, value->
                        def sqlResultMap=[:]
                        def tableColumns=[:]
                        sql.rows(value, {meta ->
                            def columns=[]
                            int colCount=meta.columnCount
                            (1..colCount).each{
                                columns.add(meta.getColumnName(it))
                            }
                            tableColumns.put(key, columns)
                        })
                        def rows=[]
                        sql.eachRow(value) {row->
                            def dbrow=[:]
                            tableColumns.get(key).each{ columnname->
                                dbrow.put(columnname, row."$columnname")
                            }
                            rows.add(dbrow)
                        }
                        sqlResultMap.put(key, rows)
                        resultSet.add(sqlResultMap)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException se) {
            println "Exception encountered in DBUtil execute() $se"
        }
        return resultSet
    }
```

It gives a list of maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but IIRC you can do something like this:

```
Map<String, List> resultSets = [:]

...

sqlStatements.each { queryAlias, query ->

    def columns=[]
    sql.eachRow(query) { row ->
        if (columns.isEmpty()) {
            int colCount = row.columnCount
            columns = (1..colCount).collect { row.getColumnName it }
        }

        resultSets[queryAlias] = columns.collect { column -> 
            row.getColumn(column) 
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** i'm almost sure you can do simply a `row as Map` and get a map from the result list without fetching each column name.

---

Non related, but i'd like to give some suggestions on that class modelling:

1. All these constants declared on the class are non related, providing a procedural code, better to refactor each of it into its own class. Each subclass can treat each db particularities, though this example doesn't show any (nor can i remember any either);
2. A factory method would be cool and could also do the validation;
3. An enum to treat each database type;
4. The `execute()` could receive the SQL it should execute, so you don't need to set the `sqlStatements` properties to execute another set of queries.

This is pretty rough, since i don't have a database to test it, but it could be something like this:

```
abstract class Database {
  enum Type { ORACLE, POSTGRES }

  String url
  String username
  String password
  abstract def getJdbc()
  abstract def getDriver()  

  static Database create(Database.Type type, Map params) {
    def db = [
      (Type.ORACLE)   : OracleDatabase, 
      (Type.POSTGRES) : PostgresDatabase
    ][type].newInstance() 

    assert (db.username = params.username), "No username given"
    assert (db.password = params.password), "No password given"
    assert (db.url = params.url), "No database URL given" 

    return db
  }

  Map<String, List> execute(sqlStatements) {
    try {
      Map<String, List> resultSets = [:]

      assert sqlStatements != null 

      def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driver)

      sqlStatements.each { queryAlias, query ->

        def columns=[]
        sql.eachRow(query) { row ->
          if (columns.isEmpty()) {
            int colCount = row.columnCount
            columns = (1..colCount).collect { row.getColumnName it }
          }

          resultSets[queryAlias] = columns.collect { column -> row.getColumn(column) }
        }
      }
      return resultSet
    }
    catch(se) {
      println "Exception encountered in DBUtil execute() $se"
      throw se
    }
  }

}

class OracleDatabase extends Database {
  def getJdbc() { "jdbc:agra:oracle" }
  def getDriver() { "com.agra.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver" }
}

class PostgresDatabase extends Database {
  def getJdbc() { "jdbc:agra:mysql" }
  def getDriver() { "org.postgresql.Driver" }
}


def dbparams = [
  "username":"johnkc", 
  "password":"johnc", 
  "url":"apple:1521;SID=ORCL;"
]

def sqlStatements = [
  "sql1":"select name, value from v\$parameter",
  "sql2":"select POO_NAME, POO_VALUE from PO_OPTION"
]

def db = Database.create(Database.Type.ORACLE, dbparams)

def result = db.execute(sqlStatements)
assert result instanceof Map
assert result.keySet().size() == 2
assert result.each { key, value -> value instanceof List }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and +1 for suggestions on re-factoring. Also I need a return type of List of maps `List<Map>`